# Workarounds for Android build script bugs

Tags: android, ant, continuous-integration

Android provides a system to [autogenerate build scripts for a test project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/testing/testing_otheride.html). Pretty cool... there's just two problems with it.

1. [The build always claims to succeed when the tests fail.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14241)
2. The tests require you to start an emulator *before* you run the `run-tests` target; the scripts provide no way to automatically start/stop the emulator.

Are you actually using the Android test scripts? If so, how do you workaround these problems? Do you leave an emulator running all the time? Read the logs for build failures? Are there other workarounds I need to know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use ant build scripts extensively for our android projects and we custom rolled the ant scripts. If you look in /tools/ant folder, you will see a file called main_rules.xml (available from android 2.3 on I think). This is the main file and has all the targets to do the builds, including launching the emulator. What you need to do, is to extract targets selectively into your build.xml file, and modify them to suit your own needs.

Doing it this way will allow you to customize pretty much everything for builds. This is about say 2-3 day task, but the benefits are manifold. It also helps developers know more about how the app is built, which is always a good thing.

Comment: Be prepared to review your changes every time the android SDK is updated.

Comment: I have done that already atleast twice, painful but it allows us to have a sophisticated release system.

Comment: So you're basically just fixing the bugs in their scripts. I guess that works. I probably won't do it this way (I think I'm learning toward the Android Maven Plugin) but it's good to know that it's possible.

Comment: Its not bugs in their scripts actually, they changed a bunch of target names, added proguard support, added debug, release targets. In that context Google did well. I didnt have to change the scripts for 2.3 and 3.0 versions of Android so lets hope that they have decided it is stable enough :)